# System time synchronization between two hosts using linuxPTP

Tags: linux, synchronization, ntp, clock

I would like to setup a high-precision system time synchronization between two machines using linuxptp.

On the first host:

- the system time is periodically synchronized using NTP using an interface connected to the Internet
- on a second interface (`eno2`), I run `ptp4l -i eno2 -S -P -4 -m`

On the second host:

- on the `enp0s31f6` interface connected to `eno2` of the first host, I run `ptp4l -s -i enp0s31f6 -S -P -4 -m`

But, on the second host, `ptp4l` won't synchronize the system time :

```
ptp4l[1024.042]: port 1: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[1024.047]: port 0: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[1024.793]: port 1: new foreign master 525400.fffe.cc6c9a-1
ptp4l[1028.792]: selected best master clock 525400.fffe.cc6c9a
ptp4l[1028.792]: foreign master not using PTP timescale
ptp4l[1028.792]: port 1: LISTENING to UNCALIBRATED on RS_SLAVE
ptp4l[1030.792]: master offset -1217822064 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    585487
ptp4l[1031.792]: master offset -1217693321 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    456366
ptp4l[1032.793]: master offset -1217396626 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    456366
ptp4l[1033.793]: master offset -1217375833 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    389459
ptp4l[1034.792]: master offset -1217740750 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    389459
ptp4l[1035.794]: master offset -608727349 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    374835
ptp4l[1036.793]: master offset -608893145 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    389459
ptp4l[1037.792]: master offset -609164618 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    389459
ptp4l[1038.793]: master offset      27325 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    374835
ptp4l[1039.792]: master offset     -32658 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    367815
ptp4l[1040.793]: master offset    -114491 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    367815
ptp4l[1041.793]: master offset     181711 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    358661
ptp4l[1042.793]: master offset      65535 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    358661
ptp4l[1043.793]: master offset     -69744 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    366265
ptp4l[1044.794]: master offset     248163 s0 freq  +34411 path delay    350007
ptp4l[1045.794]: master offset     -25172 s1 freq +75113179 path delay    350007
ptp4l[1046.718]: master offset  -75276446 s2 freq +67510258 path delay    350007
ptp4l[1046.718]: port 1: UNCALIBRATED to SLAVE on MASTER_CLOCK_SELECTED
ptp4l[1047.653]: master offset -142323559 s2 freq +60663223 path delay    350007
ptp4l[1048.592]: master offset -203217301 s2 freq +54370632 path delay    350007
[...]
ptp4l[1062.203]: master offset -596973889 s2 freq +8426740 path delay   2862004
ptp4l[1063.193]: master offset -605906062 s0 freq +8426740 path delay   2862004
ptp4l[1063.193]: port 1: SLAVE to UNCALIBRATED on SYNCHRONIZATION_FAULT
[...]
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue reason found: It was a conflict with ntp update on background...

NTP must be disabled on the client side (in this case time update is performed by the PTP client).

Comment: please, expand the solution you have found

Comment: In fact, in this case, the solution is pretty evident: conflict implies that one of NTP/PTP should be disabled... I have added "NTP must be disabled on the client side"